# time.sleep() not pausing timer in video

Tags: python, opencv, timer, sleep, bounding-box

**Background**

I have a video with people walking around different homes. I implemented 3 different timers (for 3 different people) that begin timing when the people are inside the bboxes of the homes and pause when they are outside of the bboxes of the homes. For reference, I have included a visual of what the first frame of the video looks like.

[image]

**Problem**

The *check* implemented in the code below works fine - it returns True when a person's bbox is *inside* of a home bbox and returns False otherwise. I'm having difficulties when it comes to pausing the time as a person is walking around outside of the home bbox (i.e. when a person's bbox is not inside of a home bbox). As you can see in the code below, I used `time.sleep(1)` to pause the timer for a second each time a `False` is returned, however, this doesn't seem to work. It just keeps the timer running in the background. For example, if person 1's timer is at 15 seconds before a `False` is returned, its timer should pause. Then, when a `True` is returned, its timer should resume its time from 15 seconds and increment. However, in my case right now, it keeps running the timer in the background so when a `True` is returned after a `False`, the timer suddenly shows up as 24 seconds instead of resuming from where it left off before the `time.sleep()`. How do I go about solving this issue?

```
# boxes_houses = [(#, #, #, #), (#, #, #, #), ...]

while cap.isOpened():

    # [...]

    def isInside(person, home):
        # Top-left corner
        if home['x1'] < person['x1'] and home['y1'] < person['y1']:
            # Bottom-right corner
            if person['x2'] + (person['x2'] - person['x1']) < home['x2'] + (home['x2'] - home['x1']) and person['y2'] + (person['y2'] - person['y1']) < home['y2'] + (home['y2'] - home['y1']):
                return True
        else:
            return False

    cnt_person = 0
    cnt_house = 0

    for box_person, box_house in zip(boxes_persons, boxes_houses):
        x_p1 = int(box_person[0])
        y_p1 = int(box_person[1])
        x_p2 = int(box_person[2])
        y_p2 = int(box_person[3])
        person_coords = {'x1': x_p1, 'y1': y_p1, 'x2': x_p2, 'y2': y_p2}
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x_p1, y_p1), (x_p1 + x_p2, y_p1 + y_p2), (0, 0, 0), 2, 1)
        cv2.putText(frame, "House: {}".format(cnt_house), (x1, y1 - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 0), 1)

        x_h1 = int(box_house[0])
        y_h1 = int(box_house[1])
        x_h2 = int(box_house[2])
        y_h2 = int(box_house[3])
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x_h1 , y_h1), (x_h1 + x_h2, y_h1+ y_h2), (0, 0, 255), 2, 1)
        cv2.putText(frame, "Person: {}".format(cnt_person ), (int(box_house[0]), int(box_house[1] - 5)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

        isinside_checks = []
        for house in houses:
            isinside_checks.append(isInside(person_coords, house))

        ### CHECK ###
        
        if any(inside_checks): #if persons inside the home bbox
            # print ("Person", cnt_person, ": True\n")

            if cnt_person==0:
                cv2.putText(main_frame, "Person 0 Time: {}".format(end_time-start_time), (450, 500), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0,0,0),1)
            elif cnt_person==1:
                cv2.putText(main_frame, "Person 1 Time: {}".format(end_time-start_time), (450, 500), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0,0,0),1)
            elif cnt_person==2:
                cv2.putText(main_frame, "Person 2 Time: {}".format(end_time-start_time), (450, 500), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0,0,0),1)

        else: #if persons outside the home bbox
            print ("Person", cnt_person, ": False\n") 
            time.sleep(1) # should pause the time

        cnt_person = cnt_person + 1
        cnt_house = cnt_house + 1
                       
    # show frame
    cv2.imshow('MultiTracker', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:  
        break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting challenge you have. Seems like you understand the problem, the timer will continue to check time even when you sleep the execution of the program.
I believe this is because the timer is based on the number of milliseconds since an epoch from years ago or something.

> The time() function returns the number of seconds passed since epoch. For Unix system, January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 at UTC is epoch (the point where time begins).

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time

Therefore, just because you pause your execution, that doesn’t mean that time hasn’t increased since that point in the past.

**How would I handle this problem?**

I would track the amount of time paused and subtract that from the total amount of time passed for each person.

Outside of the for loop initialise:

```
pause_times = [0, 0, 0] # the total time paused for each person
last_pause = [0, 0, 0] # the times of the last pause for each person
paused = False
```

Then where you check whether people are inside or outside the houses, update the pause times or total times appropriately:

```
if any(inside_checks): #if persons inside the home bbox
    # print ("Person", cnt_person, ": True\n")
    paused = False
    if cnt_person==0:
            cv2.putText(main_frame, "Person 0 Time: {}".format(end_time-start_time-pause_times[0]), (450, 500), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0,0,0),1)
    elif cnt_person==1:
            cv2.putText(main_frame, "Person 1 Time: {}".format(end_time-start_time-pause_times[1]), (450, 500), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0,0,0),1)
    elif cnt_person==2:
            cv2.putText(main_frame, "Person 2 Time: {}".format(end_time-start_time-pause_times[2]), (450, 500), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0,0,0),1)

else: #if persons outside the home bbox
    print ("Person", cnt_person, ": False\n")
    if not paused:  # the timer hasn't been paused for a while
        last_pause[cnt_person] = end_time # updating the pause point
        paused = True
    pause_times[cnt_person] += end_time - last_pause[cnt_person] # track the total amount of time paused for each person
    last_pause[cnt_person] = end_time
```

**Disclaimer:**

I feel obligated to say I might not totally understand your problem and I'm not an expert so my solution might be flawed. I hope that it offers you a different perspective at the very least. Cheers.